# How to trigger an alarm from within a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

So I've created a lambda function that fetches all entries in a specific S3 bucket and checks if a certain file exists in the bucket. Currently if it does exist it sets a variable called "fileExists" to true and if it doesn't it sets it to false. I'm wondering how can I trigger an alarm from the lambda function when I notice that the file doesn't exist. I have an sns topic with an email subscription already set up, just not sure how to link the lambda to an alarm.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solves your problem, but when you change something in a S3 bucket, you generate an event that can be the input for another lambda.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

Comment: so basically what I am suggesting is to create (or edit) a file in your bucket, containing the missed file names, and when this file is created (or edited), then an s3 event is generated and this will trigger another lambda form managing it.

Another option is to invoke another labda directly from your lambda. I found this link: 
https://www.sqlshack.com/calling-an-aws-lambda-function-from-another-lambda-function/